# Decrease voltage in circuit

Tags: voltage, amperage, 12v

If I have 90 VDC 3.5 A, and I want to reduce to 12 volt, in excellent efficient the amps will be around 25 A.

Can I use a 12 V L7812 regulator?

Comment: No. Read the datasheet for the L7812, it is a linear regulator capable of only 1A output current and a limitation of 35V DC input. If you don't know what a linear regulator is then you need to do some study.

Answer (score 1):

The 7812 is a linear regulator, meaning current out equals current in. The L part of the number means it is the low power version, good for only 100 mA.

You need a SMPS, a buck convertor. 90 v input and 25 A output means it will be quite a serious beast.

Answer (score 0):

No, for several reasons:

L7812 is a linear regulator which has a maximum input voltage of 35V, it's a linear shunt type regulator with maximum 1A output current, and would exceed it's dissipation limits even if it was able to handle the 95VDC input voltage.  Linear regulators are very inefficient if the Vi - Vo is large, and cannot trade off input-output IV characteristics the way you want to.

You need a switching power supply design that can convert the high voltage low current to low voltage high current output.